# Confused with GCC output

Tags: c, gcc

Recently I have installed Ubuntu and obviously I am compiling my C code in `gcc`. I came across the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i = 10,j = 20, k;
    printf("i=%d  j=%d  k=%d\n", i, j, k);
}
```

The output is coming as ::

```
i=10  j=20  k=0
```

But as far as I know that the output for the value of k should be a Garbage value since it has not been initialized.

Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: Can `0` be a garbage value?

Comment: The output is *not* from `gcc` (which is emitting only assembler code, or indirectly object code or executable) but from your program. You should compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: I am getting other garbage output, e.g. `k=32766` or `k=32764`

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the pale tick under the vote count of each answer to resolve the problem. And give us rep-whores a neat +15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot expect anything from the program you posted, `0` is a perfectly possible *garbage* value.

Also, `main()` must have a return value and it must be `int`.

Comment: Yeah I know this is just a strange program.. But the confusing part is does the Garbage value depends on system to system.? I mean my system is giving 0 everytime I run it, But in other system different Garbage Value everytime it is run.

Comment: @DibakarBose garbage is garbage, please don't try to read anything into it. At worst, the `0` will trick you into ignoring the compiler warning under the delusion "Never mind, that worked". The value `0` occurs frequently, consider too that the most common house number in an address database is `1`. Why? Because every street has that number.

Comment: Thank you very much.... I will keep this in mind... :)

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behavior, so anything is possible, including `0` to be printed.
How is `0` not a garbage value?

Comment: In some other system whenever this is run different output is coming. I mean to say that Different Garbage value is coming,.. But in my case it is staying constant.. Is there any specific reason for this behaviour?

Comment: @DibakarBose Of course there is **some**, OS-specific reason but from the standard's perspective it is completely undefined and random. Your variable is uninitialized, so it is undefined behavior and **anything might happen**.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing my confusion... I appreciate that...